# Floating point error when converting numpy ndarray to pandas dataframe index

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, numpy

I am creating an index for my dataframe in steps of 0.01 using numpy.linspace:

```
new_index = np.linspace(0, 75.6 // 0.01 / 100, 7561)))
```

This gives me the expected result, a list containing 7561 0.01 steps from 0 to 75.60:

```
print(new_index)
[0.000e+00 1.000e-02 2.000e-02 ... 7.558e+01 7.559e+01 7.560e+01]
```

However, when I use this ndarray as the index for my dataframe, the numbers are slightly off:

```
testdf = pd.DataFrame(np.ones(7561), index=np.linspace(0, tables[0]["Dehnung"].max() // 0.01 / 100, 7561), columns=["Ones"])
display(testdf)
print(testdf.index)
```

[image: correctly shown index for dataframe but contains incorrect values that are slightly off]

This causes my so created dataframe to behave ugly when concatenating it with other dataframes with the same index with 0.01 steps. Is there any way I can fix this?

Comment: Don't index with floats? You can try `round` your index, or `merge_asof` if you really need the float values. You can also work with [Fractions](https://docs.python.org/3/library/fractions.html) package.

Comment: You are right, I can just scale everything by 100 and use integers as the index, I did not think of that. Thanks

Comment: Are they **really** different or are they just displayed to different precision? Most real numbers can't be represented exactly as floats.

Comment: They are really different, at least different enough for pandas to refuse to put them in the same row when using concat with axis=1. I'm using NumPy without pandas now.